# Solving an "almost differential" equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, supremum-and-infimum

This problem comes from a problem set that my calculus professor assigned to me.

> Determine all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$
> f(x) = f\Bigl(\frac{x}{2}\Bigr) + f'(x)\, \frac{x}{2} 
> \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
> $$
> The answer is all linear ones, for the record.

I have an elementary, though ad-hoc, solution using specific supremum and infimum properties. What I wonder is whether or not problems of this type are prone to a specific or "known" method, and if so, how this method can be applied to this particular problem.

I tried to prove it in a more standard manner but didn't find something useful: I differentiated both sides two times and deduced $f''(0)=0$. Inductively, one can prove $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for $n\geq 2$. Now, would Taylor series suffice to prove $f(x)=ax+b$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: f(x) = x works. f(x) = constant works.

Comment: Please show your solution.

Comment: You could use a log-scale on the independent variable to convert this into a delay differential equation, then use the method of steps. Not sure how you would handle the initial condition though, maybe start with a condition on $r = g(-\infty) = f(\log 0)$ and find an $r$-indexed family of solutions?